# Why do Youtube and many other video pages play on page load?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, autoplay

There are a lot pages like Youtube starting their videos with sound on load:
https://www.arte.tv/de/videos/091148-000-A/forschung-fake-und-faule-tricks/

Sound should be only allowed after click, whitelisting or if multiple videos on the page have been viewed before. This is not needed here.

What is the difference between these pages and a simple HTML5 Video element using *autoplay* attribute or Javascript *videoElement.play()*?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Chrome there is another thing which influences if a page can autoplay media or not. It's the [Media Engagement Index](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#mei). It's basically a number which is larger if you used to play media on that particular page before. If it's large enough the page is allowed to autoplay.

Comment: Thanks. Using Chrome, I checked *chrome://media-engagement/* and found one of my own pages rated with a solid score (between procastination services and porn). It is true, autoplay with sound works there. But it also works on random tv pages I never used before like https://www.checkeins.de/sendungen/kinderfilme-kinderdokus/wir-freundschaft-grenzenlos-video-106.html

Comment: The page you linked doesn't autoplay when I visit it with Chrome. My guess is that the actual video is served with an iframe from a different domain. That domain probably has a high Media Engagement Index score on your machine based on your history.